# Mount Content Database

Tags: upgrade

I have restored a copy of production db to our UAT SQL environment. When I run the Mount-SPContentDatabase, after 10 seconds I am receiving the successful message however When I checked the web-application there is not data. The content db size is around 90GB. Before it usually takes up to 30 minutes to Mount a database.

[image]

1. Create a database via SharePoint.
2. Dismount the database with powershell
3. Restore the content to newly created db
4. Using Powersehll to Mount database

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may troubleshoot the below:

1. Read the content database using PowerShell from the attached web application.
2. Verify the size from the target migrated web application.
3. If size is fine...Restart the server.

If above does not work, follow the below steps:

2. Unmount the content database
3. If you have AG group configured in database... make sure the primary listner (server) is always on.
4. Restart the SQL service.
5. Mount the content database back.

Comment: thanks SPM for your information, after following your suggestions I still have the issue, please read my comments.

Comment: Do you create a new db in sql server and restore the content on that or do you restore the content on the db that was created with SharePoint web app?

Comment: We need to restore the database then mount it to target web application.

Comment: So you create a db using sql management or from SharePoint?

Comment: Restore the database from sqlserver, then use the PowerShell mount command.

Comment: I can now see all the site collections, however when I check the URL, it shows the production URL not the UAT URL. For some reason its pointing to production.

Comment: Check iis binding and alternate access mapping URL....

Comment: thanks again, as you can see in the image my webapplication name is http://devsp02:13922 but site collection that i restored is something else and pointing to the production.